# An integral inequality Problem consisting of Trigonometric functions

Tags: definite-integrals, integral-inequality

$$2\int_a^b \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{a \sin x}{b+a\cos x}\right) \, dx \geq (b-a) \left(
{\sqrt{ab}}+\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)/2} \,  \right)$$

We have to show this. I have only written a part of the complete problem. If I am able to solve this, I can tackle the rest. The actual problem is in cyclic summation. One condition : $0 < a < b< \pi/2$

Comment: I edited with LaTeX. Why is not showing?

Comment: @AnuranChowdhury Here's our MathSE bible: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: *"I edited with LaTeX. Why is not showing?"* From [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference): "2. **For inline formulas, enclose the formula in `$...$`.  For displayed formulas, use `$$...$$`.**  "

Comment: Thanks ! I think it's working now.

Comment: Please, Anuran, to check the most recent edit, because that's not what I saw that you wrote.  Otherwise, if the edit is aok, great!

Comment: It's correct now. I re edited previously as some might think of it as two different summands.

Comment: What was/is the original problem (X), and what was the part you claimed to have solved, and why you think this question (Y) is exactly what's needed to solve, ultimately X.  There's a phenomenon  (called the [X-Y problem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiY29Lvvt7UAhUFTSYKHaX-C_QQFggwMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F66377%2Fwhat-is-the-xy-problem&usg=AFQjCNFXK9Ae-7TMNq233MZYHqOVBoKQ9g) that happens all too frequently.  Read the link (not very long), and consider the questions I just asked.

Comment: Please understand, this is in no way meant as a criticism.  It seems you've proceeded and put a lot of time into solving X (the original question/problem you encountered), which leads you to believe if you can solve Y, you can then solve X.  This phenomenon may not at all apply.  I just mention it because most of us have gotten derailed by this at some point.  And I ask only because is saves you (and us) a lot of time, pain, effort, etc. in cases in which the path toward a solution doesn't involve Y.

Comment: If $a=b=1$ then $\dfrac{a\sin x}{b+a\cos x} = \dfrac{\sin x}{ 1+\cos x} = \tan\dfrac x 2,$ so $\tan^{-1} \left( \dfrac{a\sin x}{b + a\cos x}\right) = \dfrac x 2,$ and you have $$2\int_a^b \frac x 2 \, dx = b^2 - a^2 = (b-a)(b+a) \text{ (which in that case is $0$.)} $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy  If $a =  b = 1$, then indeed $0 \geq 0$.  And so...?  Indeed, whenever $a, b$ are in the domain of the function, and $a=b$, we have $0\geq 0$

Comment: @amWhy : So the point is that one might think about what changes would result from perturbing those values of $a$ and $b.$ Here one seeks inequalities rather than exact values. $\qquad$

Comment: But the OP notes the following condition on a, b: $0 < a < b< \dfrac \pi 2$

Comment: I think @MichaelHardy is looking for a perturbation solution...

Comment: @user121330 : I didn't necessarily mean "perturbation" in a sense admitting a standard definition.